# How to make steam login function in meteor.js

Tags: meteor, steam, steam-web-api

https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/accounts-steam has got some packages to do this, but there are no some information how to use it. So, I need manual or some advices how to make steam auth function in my meteor js applicationю

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you configure the steam API? Have your tried `Meteor.loginWithSteam()`?

Comment: I tried to use this code : https://github.com/Maxpain177/meteor-steam. But I have got exception: "Already registered the steam OAuth service". Also, I don't know what function I should to call when user clicks on "Steam Login Button"

Comment: @VladimirYumatov the function is what MasterAM wrote `Meteor.loginWithStream()` if it says already registered the steam OAuth did you try to do that? It says it's already exists or maybe you have multiple packages for it?